# Program 'tempCodeRunnerFile.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:110 VS Code error

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

Program 'tempCodeRunnerFile.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:110
This error comes up in few programs some times. I can't find any solution. Please help me with one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This could be because of your antivirus. it will assume the file created during compilation to be an virus and won't permit it to run.

- Temporary turn off your antivirus.
- Uninstall your antivirus
- Or Try changing name of the file

This is what helped me hope it will help you as well

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found out that my powershell has problem! So change default terminal by selecting it in vscode terminal dropdown menu (ctrl+j) then restart vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I had mcAfee antivirus and it kept deleting the exe files and so it wont run. i would suggest you shut those antiviruses off.
I think Real-time scanning is the real reason it happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the antivirus running in your pc as it deletes the .exe files considering as a virus.
Turn off the real time scanning of your antivirus and try executing the program.