# Programs installed with Chocolatey cannot be executed

Tags: windows, powershell, git-bash, chocolatey

I am having a problem with programs that I installed with Chocolatey - namely that they cannot be executed. I am running Windows 10.

1. Chocolatey itself works - I can download and upgrade programs
2. the folder C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ is set in PATH under System Variables

I have a couple of packages installed, but I'll use two as an example here: ffmpeg and nano

If I run either  `nano --version` or  `ffmpeg--version` with **Powershell** I get in both cases:

> ResourceUnavailable: Program 'nano.exe' failed to run: Access deniedAt line:1 >char:1
>
> '+ nano
>
> '+ ~~~~.

And the same for ffmpeg.

The weird thing is if I run the same with **GitBash** I get for nano:

> GNU nano, version 4.9.3
>
> (C) 1999-2011, 2013-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> (C) 2014-2020 the contributors to nano
>
> Email: nano@nano-editor.org    Web: https://nano-editor.org/
>
> Compiled options: --enable-utf8

and for ffmpeg

> bash: /c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably because `nano` is part of the Git installation (try `which nano` - you will get `/usr/bin/nano` and not `/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/nano`), so the `nano` you successfully run there isn't even Chocolatey's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had a similar issue here and people thought antivirus software was the cause: [Program 'tempCodeRunnerFile.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:110 VS Code error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639505/program-tempcoderunnerfile-exe-failed-to-run-access-is-deniedat-line1-char1)

Comment: Thats it!! I'm using Avast and it secretely blocked the running. I deactivated it, testet it. It works. Now (weirdly) I get a pop up that the execution of a program is stopped, I see the path of the program (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\...) and I can add an exception by the click of a button. This will likely work until the next update, as I see in the list of exception also a hash value...